# Ruby raise exception if ARGV is empty or nil

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
region = ARGV[0]
instance_name = ARGV[1]
```

This way its works:

```
raise RuntimeError, 'empty argument' if ARGV[0].nil?
raise RuntimeError, 'empty argument' if ARGV[1].nil?
```

This way its not works:

I tried all of them

```
ARGV.each do |a|
  raise RuntimeError, 'empty argument' if "#{a}".nil?
  raise RuntimeError, 'empty argument' if a.nil?
  raise RuntimeError, 'empty argument' if "#{a}".empty?
  raise RuntimeError, 'empty argument' if a.empty?
end
```

How should I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: how can you have a `nil` first argument and a second argument as not `nil`?

Comment: I want to raise an exception if the script run without one of the arguments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`raise RuntimeError, 'empty argument' if ARGV[0].nil?` works because an attempt to access any index in a Ruby array that doesn't exist will return `nil`.

```
ARGV[123213] #=> nil
```

`ARGV.each` will attempt to loop over the contents of `ARGV` but if `ARGV` is empty the contents of the block will never be executed so none of your `if` conditions will actually be run.

If you want to check that 2 arguments have been provided you can check the length `ARGV.length == 2`.

It is technically possible that an empty string has been passed for one of the arguments. For instance if the script is run using

```
ruby myscript.rb ""
```

So you can check

```
if ARGV.length == 2 && ARGV.none?(&:empty?)
  # 2 arguments provided...
```

Comment: `ARGV.length == 2 && ARGV.none?(&:empty?)` is the condition for if the valid arguements *were* passed. i.e. there were 2 args and neither was empty. So in your example the exception would be raised when the arguments were correct (the opposite of what you want!) One approach is to use `unless` e.g. `raise RuntimeError, 'incorrect number of arguments' unless ARGV.length == 2 && ARGV.none?(&:empty?)`